# Fetch POST does not 'write' after 6 attempts

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have event listeners on my code that are supposed to trigger a POST fetch command to a NodeJS script that outputs the content to a file. While the code currently works, it stalls after 6 calls are made. For me to get more, I need to manually stop my NodeJS application and start it again in order to get 6 more. What am I missing with this code that is triggering this behavior?

```
dashboard.getParametersAsync().then(function (parameters) {
  parameters.forEach(function (p) {
      p.addEventListener(tableau.TableauEventType.ParameterChanged,onParameterChange);
  });
});

function onParameterChange (parameterChangeEvent) {
   parameterChangeEvent.getParameterAsync().then(function (param) {
      parameterIndicator = 'Parameter'
      const details = {
        method: 'POST',
        //body: JSON.stringify(data),
        //  headers: {
        //      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        //  }
      };
    
 fetch(`https://serverurl/${param.name}/${parameterIndicator}/${getDateTimestamp()}/${dashboardName}/${param.name}/${worksheetData}`, details).then(
 (res) => {console.log(res);});
 });
}
```

NodeJS:

```
const app = require('express')();
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  var readStream = fs.createReadStream('index.html','utf8');
  readStream.pipe(res);
});

app.post('/:fieldName/:flag/:time/:dashboard/:identifier/:user', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('POST message received', req.params);
    if (req.params && req.params.fieldName) {
        await fs.appendFileSync('./changeLog.csv', `${req.params.fieldName},${req.params.flag},${req.params.time},${req.params.dashboard},${req.params.identifier},${req.params.user}\n`);
    }
});
```

*Edit, based on one of the responses I got, I added a console output after the 'fetch' command, and in the browser i see it increment past 6. However, my application stops receiving the messages after 6. See image below.
[image]

Comment: any errors in the server logs?

Comment: The post handling isn't sending back a response.

Comment: @epascarello I couldn't see anything obvious. I modified the post to show a console output 'test', to show i can print it on the screen more than 6 times.

Comment: @ChrisG, I am absolute beginner here, if you can expand on that answer I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Chrome will allow 6 concurrent connections per domain, so its probably refusing to make any more connections until it receives a response to the ones already in progress

Comment: @andrew what part of the code needs to be modified for the response to be handled appropriately as you suggest?

Comment: @530529 in your post route, you basically need to end the request and send a response back e.g. `res.sendStatus(200)`, otherwise you are just hanging the HTTP connections until they eventually timeout

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with express but i'd guess you may need to close the connection with `res.end()`

Comment: Yes, like James and andrew said, you need to send back a server reply using the `res` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to send response from the `POST` in all cases.
2. You are using `appendFileSync` function (which is synchronous) with `await` - it indicates, that you may need to read some docs about it.

Here is the code, which must fix your problem:

```js
app.post('/:fieldName/:flag/:time/:dashboard/:identifier/:user', (req, res) => {
    console.log('POST message received', req.params);
    if (req.params && req.params.fieldName) {
        fs.appendFileSync('./changeLog.csv', `${req.params.fieldName},${req.params.flag},${req.params.time},${req.params.dashboard},${req.params.identifier},${req.params.user}\n`);
        return res.send('OK')
    }
    // Bad request
    res.status(400).end()
});
```

Comment: To add onto this: the reason why you need to send a response (even if it's empty) is because the browser will only handle a number (6) of open connections to a hostname at any time.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! As a follow-up question, since I may have multiple users logged on the application concurrently, should I change the appendFileSync to a 'Async' method or would it make no difference for me?